# R remove last vector from all elements in list

Tags: r

I have the following data (this is a sample of the first two list in the data):

```
fpb<-structure(list(`1` = structure(c(-2.47981979633349, 8.6216816156608, 
7.68647649257742, -7.76968675333804, -7.9144137972946, 18.2364354703205, 
-23.4593879621981, 40.469801451573, -50.3727468353916, 54.564318651129, 
50.040496691847, -64.389939923162, -78.3356428303116), .Names = c("11", 
"112", "113", "117", "118", "133", "134", "141", "142", "146", 
"147", "149", "150")), `2` = structure(c(-2.6879977130791, 2.25612015337798, 
-2.90776581499623, 2.36705960916142, 2.02508598649777, -2.45340515893393, 
-2.49445436737825, 27.6089374776595, -33.6920201405386, 29.5037874749887, 
29.1127907940704, -39.4568756080229, -45.2357483355595), .Names = c("21", 
"22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "237", "238", "240", "241", 
"242", "243"))))
```

I want to check if in each sublist there is even or odd numbers. If there are odd numbers, I want to remove the last vector.

here is what I tried but I just get the first vector from each list instead.

```
fpb2<-fpb
for (i in 1:500){
  if(length(fpb[[i]]%%2!=0)){N<-fpb[[i]][-length(fpb[[i]])]}
  fpb2[i]=N
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the `length` of the `list` elements with `lengths`, check whether it is odd (`%%2==1`), use that index to subset the `list`, loop through the elements and remove the last element with `head` and update the `list`.

```
i1 <- lengths(fpb)%%2==1
fpb[i1] <- lapply(fpb[i1], head, -1)
```

Comment: how do i check whether the number of vectors in the list are even or odd numbers for lapply?

Comment: @Ash Updated the post

Comment: works like a charm. Thank you for the explanation too!

Comment: for the same list above, I am trying to sum certain vectors using the code `getinvbootnum<-lapply(fbp, FUN=function(x) seq(1,length(x),by=2))
invboot<-lapply(fbp, FUN=function(x) sum(x[getinvbootnum]))` However, i get the error `Error in x[getinvbootnum] : invalid subscript type 'list'`... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `getinvbootnum` is a `list`  YOu may need to `unlist` it

Comment: @Ash Try `Map("[", fpb, getinvbootnum)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129823/discussion-between-ash-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2):

is this what you are looking for?

```
lapply(fpb, function(x) {if(length(x)%%2){x <- x[-length(x)];x}else{x}})
```

sample :

```
> fpb
#$`1`
#       112        113        117        118        133        134        141        142        146        147        149 
#  8.621682   7.686476  -7.769687  -7.914414  18.236435 -23.459388  40.469801 -50.372747  54.564319  50.040497 -64.389940 
#       150 
#-78.335643 

#$`2`
#        21         22         23         24         25         26         27        237        238        240        241 
#-2.687998   2.256120  -2.907766   2.367060   2.025086  -2.453405  -2.494454  27.608937 -33.692020  29.503787  29.112791 
#       242        243 
#-39.456876 -45.235748 

> lapply(fpb, function(x) {if(length(x)%%2){x <- x[-length(x)];x}else{x}})
#$`1`
#       112        113        117        118        133        134        141        142        146        147        149 
#  8.621682   7.686476  -7.769687  -7.914414  18.236435 -23.459388  40.469801 -50.372747  54.564319  50.040497 -64.389940 
#       150 
#-78.335643 

$`2`
#        21         22         23         24         25         26         27        237        238        240        241 
# -2.687998   2.256120  -2.907766   2.367060   2.025086  -2.453405  -2.494454  27.608937 -33.692020  29.503787  29.112791 
#       242 
#-39.456876
```

Comment: Your logical condition is not complete